# C++ Using Loops to Print Phrase in a Box

Tags: c++, loops

I am having trouble centering the words in the box. The code is supposed to accept any word or phrase and display it in a box like the one at the top of the code example. I have managed to print my input within the box, but cannot figure out how to stack the words one by one and center them. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
/*Write a program that reads a sequence of words and then prints them in a box, with each word centered, like this:

+----------+
|  Hello   |
|   C++    |
|programmer|
+----------+
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  string s;
  int max_word_len = 1;
  cout << "Please enter a word or sentence: " << endl;
  getline(cin, s);

  for (int i = 0; i < max_word_len; i++) 
  {
    int word_len = s.length();
    string box = "+";
    for (int i = 0; i < word_len; i++)
    {
        box += "-";
    }
    box += "+";
    cout << box << endl; 
    cout << "|" << s << "|" << endl;
    cout << box <<endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if a word is too long and doesn't fit one line? What would you like to do then?

Comment: @bruno I was typing in the answer, then I saw your comment and I feel like solving homework question now. I mean what you are saying does make a lot of sense. In terms of code also, no need of loop. (-.-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my implementation, hope this will help you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string str;
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    getline(std::cin, str);
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    size_t max_length = 0;
    do {
        std::string temp;
        ss >> temp;
        if (temp.length() != 0)
            v.push_back(temp);
        max_length = std::max(max_length, temp.length());
    } while(ss);
    std::cout << "+";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < max_length; i++)
        std::cout << "-";
    std::cout << "+" << std::endl;
    for (auto &i : v) {
        std::cout << "|";
        auto sp = max_length - i.length();
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sp/2; j++)
            std::cout << " ";
        std::cout << i;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sp - sp/2; j++)
            std::cout << " ";
        std::cout << "|" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "+";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < max_length; i++)
        std::cout << "-";
    std::cout << "+" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
hello c++ programmer
```

**Output**

```
+----------+
|  hello   |
|   c++    |
|programmer|
+----------+
```

Comment: It is more clear to use a *while* rather than a *do while* because the input string can be empty. To produce the spaces before the word then before the ending | you can remove your loops just using *std::setw*. To produce the two serials of - you can also remove your loops using *std::string(<n>, '-')*. Just my 2 cents